# How to add error response format in Swagger for a Spring-boot project based on webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, swagger-codegen

I don't know how to add an error response format in Swagger for a Spring-boot project based on webflux. 
In all the tutorials that I have read I have only found how to add 200 response format but I also need to show the format of the error (the `map<String, Object>`) generated by spring-boot. Any ideas please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out yourself, the default error response payload is a `Map` (specifically a `Map<String, Object>`, see [DefaultErrorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(...)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/error/DefaultErrorAttributes.html#getErrorAttributes-org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest-boolean-)). Specifying this as the error response will not get you what you want.

Instead you can specify the error response payload creating a `class` with the fields of the default error map.

```
public class SpringErrorPayload {
    public long timestamp;
    public int status;
    public String error;
    public String exception;
    public String message;
    public String path;

    public SpringErrorPayload(long timestamp, int status, String error, String exception, String message, String path) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.status = status;
        this.error = error;
        this.exception = exception;
        this.message = message;
        this.path = path;
    }

    //removed getters and setters
}
```

Then, by adding a `class` to the `response` attribute of the `@ApiResponse` of your method, you will get the desired result

```
@ApiOperation("Create new something")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 201, message = "New something successfully created"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request, adjust before retrying", response = SpringErrorPayload.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error", response = SpringErrorPayload.class )
})
@ResponseStatus(CREATED)
public SomethingPayload createSomething(@Valid @RequestBody final NewSomethingPayload newSomethingPayload) {
    return somethingService.createSomething(newSomethingPayload);
}
```

[image: Swagger result]

Comment: I have forgotten that I need this for a spring-boot project based on webflux, the only solution that I have found to customize error response is to provide an implementation of [ErrorAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/error/ErrorAttributes.html)

Comment: This solution answers also my new requirement. Thank you.I don't know why I have changed my idea yesterday, sorry for that @Misantorp

Comment: No problem, glad I could help out